# “Error occurred running Grails CLI:connect timed out" when running grails 3

Tags: grails, grails3

I already set the environment for GRAILS_HOME and JAVA_HOME, and its succeed when i tried to "grails -version". But when I use grails command, i got “Error occurred running Grails CLI:connect timed out" . 
Anyone know whats the problem?

Comment: Is this as a result of your previous question & you're in offline mode? This may be of use, https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9393

Comment: I can't even connect to grails prompt, i tried to create apps with --offline and got the same error

Comment: If you create the app at http://start.grails.org and then run `grailsw run-app` in that project, does it work?

Comment: i get "you must be connected to the internet the first time you use the grails wrapper"